# How to reset in PowerBI the data in table

Tags: azure, iot, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I send data from Azuer IoT Hub with Stream Analytics to Power BI and show it with the Stack Column Chart. I Send the Productname and amount=1.

[image]

The amount will be show as Sum for a product. I send new amount it will be added to last value.

How can i reset the value amount of one or all product. I will send a command to reset the value of product amount.

I use the PowerBI for free online.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to clear the entire table. You could do it with this API call: http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#reference/datasets/table-rows/clear-the-rows-in-a-table

Comment: I would like to do this with Azuer IoT Hub and Stream Analytics ;)